# wordpress create mobile responsive blocks in gutenberg editor

Tags: wordpress, responsive, wordpress-gutenberg

This is my first time using `wordpress` and the `gutenberg` editor and while I am using gutenberg templates to quickly cook up a website I find no option or whatsoever to adjust the layout of any gutenberg block for mobile or tablet screens .

I am using `wordpress 5.8` and there is the option to update to `5.8.1` but I do not think this is the problem .
I have googled this problem only to see older posts with older versions of wordpress to have options for mobile and tablet which do not exist on my `wordpess` version .

[image]

Comment: There is currently no built-in tool for this. You will need to rely on your theme or custom plugins to implement this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own css style in a [child theme](https://learn.wordpress.org/lesson-plan/create-a-basic-child-theme-for-block-themes/), which I think is the easiest way to solve your problem without touching the code too much.